# How to release android update version of app for regular and pre-installed app

Tags: android

Recently I released updated version of my app, that works good. My first version is also a pre-installed app, during update version I released updated version but now my problem is on pre-installed app having traking id for Google Analytics
when I released new version the pre-installed version got override. Is there a way to release update version for pre-installed app and I need to know how to get back the trackID.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try to explain the question more clear. Also note, what version of GA library you are using.

Comment: My concern is not about GA, I have tracking code on pre-installed app to identify this is from pre-installed app. When I update new version the old version of pre-installed app got override. So, now that becomes normall app. TackID is only on pre-installed app. When I release new version, how can I distinguish regular update and pre-installed update.

Comment: but both pre-installed app and app from the Google Play have equal version number now, right?

Comment: When I release pre-installed app, at that time both versions are equal. After that I released two versions. In that two updates are regular update. I don't know how to release updates for pre-installed app.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your pre-release app has `versionCode=1`. The first version of deployed on Google Play app was also `1`. But as you've said, you already have 2 updates on it and google play forced you to increment version number, let's say to 3.

In conclusion, if user has pre installed app - his version code will be 1.
If he updated from market - most probably he will have latest version number -3. Or at least two.

The point is that you can be pretty sure that at that moment of time, when you already published two updates, users, who have `version=1` are users with preisntalled app, while users with `version>1` are users with app from market.

Considering this, you can use the app version number from GA to differentiate these users.

Does that make sense?

Comment: I Agree, but those who already updated their app those users are now regular user.Here I loss pre-instal user id. I want to keep track after the pre-install user update.
Is there any option to upload seprate apk verson for pre-install users?

Comment: Please, define "pre-install user". It seems that we are talking about different things.

Comment: Pre-install user means the device ship with my app. For example Hangouts, youtube, GMail, etc...